# How do i get rid of the black shady lines on the object?

Tags: modeling

How do i get rid of these black shades on the given object which is part of a panel for a Sci-Fi crate? It looks ugly and i'm stuck.

FYI- I've already tried flipping the normals, tried auto smoothing it out in object data properties but nothing seems to work.
[image: unwanted black shades]

Comment: You should upload your file or at least the part that correspond to the issue. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload.

Comment: Looks like probably z-fighting. Check for duplicate/overlapping geometry.

Comment: As Rich Sedman says it looks like z-fighting. Move the panel away from the main object slightly in the Y direction (g>y).